# Why ORDER BY on column alias is not working as expected?

Tags: mysql

Why isn't this query working correctly if I use a column alias in the `ORDER BY` clause?

```
SELECT AVG(`sales`) AS 'Average Sales' FROM `tb_customers` 
GROUP BY `customer_id` ORDER BY 'Average Sales' DESC
```

But if I don't use the column alias in the `ORDER BY` then it is working fine:

```
SELECT AVG(`sales`) AS 'Average Sales' FROM `tb_customers` 
GROUP BY `customer_id` ORDER BY AVG(`sales`) DESC
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`'Average Sales'` is a string, not a column name. So you are attempting to order all rows by the same value, which does nothing. Change your query to make it a proper column name by enclosing it in backticks instead:

```
SELECT AVG(`sales`) AS `Average Sales` 
FROM `tb_customers` 
GROUP BY `customer_id` 
ORDER BY `Average Sales` DESC
```

Comment: oh that's a new thing I came to know. Till now I only heard of enclosing alias names within quotes if it possesses any space. But if I don't use function in my query and just write a normal query e.g. **SELECT `customer_name` AS name FROM `tb_customers` ORDER BY name DESC** then the alias does work. Why?

Comment: It's the single quotes that are the problem. If you wrote `SELECT \`customer_name\` AS 'name' FROM \`tb_customers\` ORDER BY 'name' DESC` it wouldn't sort properly because `'name'` is a constant string. It's a bit inconsistent that MySQL lets you put a column alias in single quotes, it would be much better if it didn't.

Comment: No, you couldn't understand my this question. I am not using single quotes around **name** in `ORDER BY`. See query in my first comment. Actually I asked If I don't use function e.g. `AVG` etc. then the alias does work in `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: It works because `name` is a valid column name. You could put a function there and it would still work e.g. `SELECT MAX(\`customer_name\`) AS name FROM \`tb_customers\` ORDER BY name DESC`

Comment: So I concluded: If alias has space then use backtick rather than quotes in column alias as well as in `ORDER BY` clause. And if alias has no spaces, then no need to use either backtick or quotes.

Comment: @3185166 exactly! sorry if I was confusing in my answers.

Comment: And good luck figuring out which average belongs to which customer!

Comment: @Strawberry I presume OP removed the parts of the query that didn't cause the problem...

Comment: The OP doesn't (or didn't) know the difference between backticks and inverted commas. Fair enough; they're new to this. But under the circumstances, that presumption is a bit of a stretch.